# Best non-CSS HTML template?

Tags: html, templates, web, resources

This is the situation:
For my AP US Government & Politics class, we have to create wiki pages for our "countries" in the school's Diplomacy Games. I kind of want to blow the other kids out of the water with my page. I can program well, and have some experience with HTML (although not much), so modifying a template would be easy for me. The question is, where can I get a nice one-page template for a simple, yet awesome country homepage? It has to be only HTML (no CSS), so I assume it won't be able to be all that snazzy. But, does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: If there's no CSS, it's going to be an image or completely unstyled.

Comment: Why no CSS? "Best" by what criteria?

Comment: True, but there are WSIWYG editors for this type of page, so I assume there must _some_ way to make it look nice..

Comment: @Blender `<i>`, `<font>`, etc...

Comment: Are you allowed to use in-line style tags?

Comment: no CSS because PBWorks does not support it (i know, it's REALLY lame). As far as what "best" means, to be honest, I would use anything right now, as long as it looks good. If you could direct me to a good WSIWYG editor, I'd be much appreciative too..

Comment: @intermernet Yes! you can.

Comment: Inline style tags are CSS. I suggest you rephrase the question to clarify.

Comment: @JoeBabcock put all your CSS in style tags and you're good to go. You can now actually use any template, including ones with separate CSS files, and then just copy the CSS into a <style> block in the <head> of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost impossible to enforce a "no CSS" rule as you can always put the CSS into a `<style>` block in the `<head>` section of your HTML file.

Given a CSS file with:

```
table{
font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
width:100%;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
td, th 
{
font-size:1em;
border:1px solid #98bf21;
padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;
}
```

You'd just copy it out of that file and stick it in the `<head>` section of the HTML file.

```
<head>
<title> My Awesome Country Page </title>
<style>
    table{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    td, th 
    {
    font-size:1em;
    border:1px solid #98bf21;
    padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;
    }
</style>
</head>
```

Hope that helps.